# I want to make bidirectional (Duplex) communication between Xamarin and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, duplex

I usually use wsdualhttpbinding and nettcpbinding when doing bidirectional communication with WCF.
However, Xamarin thinks that they can not use them but only use BasicHttpBinding.
Therefore, in this case I would like to give you advice on how to accomplish two-way communication.

Because it translates, it may be strange English. Excuse me

Comment: Can you post code you have tried using?

Comment: If WCF doesn't work look into using SignalR

Answer (score 0):

You can't now.  But maybe soon.  There is a discussion about it: [Could you guys let some of the team members go to update WCF of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1688)